# OpenID2.0 for Google accounts has gone away error from asp.net c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oauth, google-openid, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate social logins to my asp.net application. I'm using Default ASP.NET 4.5 Templates for OAuth in Visual Studio 2012. In the AuthConfig.cs file I have uncommented the line

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
```

which added a Google button in Login page. When the Google button is clicked it shows " OpenID2.0 for Google accounts has gone away " error.

Other social logins like facebook, twitter are working fine.

Comment: Indeed; this has gone away. You'll need to transfer to an alternative form of  google auth - most likely OAuth 2.0 (OpenID Connect) endpoints; see the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect - and here's how we did that in SEDE: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/6aa692845193b7843eb26a7f32a0bb0e666ecf6b

Comment: @Marc Gravell Thank you. Your link is informative. But I'm using Default Template provided in VS 2012. How to modify/do something in Google Oauth.

Comment: you'll have to either change the code following the google guidance, or find an updated template if that is too challenging

Comment: Thank you Mr.Marc Gravell. Let me do some research on this :)

Comment: Having same problem; any sample code how to migrate to new OpenID ?